# Driving 120 V socket from two different switches/circuits

Tags: mains, parallel

I have a garage 120 V overhead light connected to a light switch at the entrance.  When the garage door opener engages, another 120 V light on the opener lights up but that light with one bulb is quite dim for the large garage.  I would like to take the wires from the garage door opener light and connect them in parallel to the overhead light in the garage.

In that way, the overhead light would turn on either via the switch at the entrance or when the garage door engages.  Will that work, and what happens if the light switch is on AND the garage door engages at the same time?

Comment: It is likely that any modification or added connection to the garage door opener will violate electrical safety regulations.

Comment: If you know what you're doing, you can hook up a relay to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the responses

Answer (score 1):

No, based on the information provided you can not connect the door opener's light in parallel with the ceiling light. We don't have enough information to determine what will happen to the door opener if you turn on the light from the wall switch, but I would absolutely not do it in my garage.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You could place a relay in parallel with the "dim" light that is controlled by the garage door opener, and place the relay contact in parallel with the existing light switch for the overhead light. The overhead light will then be on when the garage door opener's output is enabled, regardless of the light switch. When the garage door opener's output is disabled, the light switch has control.

Schematic for single pole light switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUeZtQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Schematic for dual pole light switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCvK5k.png)</sup>

In each case, the area inside the dashed box is what is added to the existing circuit.

And, of course, make sure the relay contacts are rated for at least 120VAC and the required current for the overhead light.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the schematic.  Will try that.